# ManyToMany relation don't create all tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two simple entities. One is for services, and one that contains products. Many services can have many products.

For example, service1 is composed from product2 and product6, service2 is composed from product1 and product2, ...

I've created the products entity (id and name), and then created the service entity with id, name and:

```
 /**
   * @var ArrayCollection
   *
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="service")
   */
   private $products;
```

But this only generate two real tables, one called service and one called product. And service table even don't have a field called products.

I think that this must create another table called service_product to store the relationship between the two tables.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only define the relationship like this and do nothing else in the product entity it's not gonna work. What you have defined here is only the inverse side because of the

```
mappedBy="service"
```

To define the owning side of the relation you need to use

```
inversedBy
```

Also I suppose that the property in the Product entity is named services and not service like what you have in the mappedBy.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a code that works perfectly on my side. I created the `Product` and `Service` entities in the console with the generator, then only added the `ManyToMany` line in the Service entity. When I did a `doctrine:schema:update --force`, 3 tables were created: Product, Service and service_product.

The Product entity:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

And the Service entity:

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $products;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

These are very basics entities. You should also add a getter and a setter in the Service entity for the products property, and probably declare the products as an ArrayCollection in the constructor.

Comment: I've removed the mappedBy property, and still don't work. This is  many-to-many unidirectional. So, I don't need to do nothing on Product entity (I think). First, you create products, then you create a service a add products to it.

Comment: Exactly, if you want an unidirectional relation you don't need to add `mappedBy` or `inversedBy` in any of the entities. I updated my response to give you an example of a code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined both side `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` in both entities

```
//Service.php (Service class)
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="services", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_service_table_name")
 */
protected $products;
```

And

```
//Product.php (Product class)
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="products", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_service_table_name")
 */
protected $services;
```

Just in case to have a specific name for the join table you can define it as mentioned in the source above but make sure the names should be equal

Comment: This is a many-to-many unidirectional. I followed the example at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional. But the joint table is not created.

Comment: Sorry but if it was Unidirectional relationship, then the mapping would be different base on your example you provided for me. On the other hand did you run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to update your schema and create the databases?